# Selenium alert only shows in debug mode

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, alert

I am testing a site page using Webdriver/Java which contains many fields.  One of the fields is a dropdown box (or select box) and it contains validation upon losing focus (e.g. tabbing out).  So if I select a particular option in the dropdown and tab to the next field, an alert box will pop up saying "You cannot choose that!".

Now I am doing code that checks for the presence of the alert box, and accepts it, however this is only working for me in DEBUG mode.  When running the test (i.e. not in debug) I get "Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for alert to be present Build info: version: '2.53.0'".

I understand that this is probably a timing issue since it works in DEBUG mode, but I can't understand why as I'm using ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent().  The code where this is failing is here:

```
WebElement currentElement = driver.findElement(By.id("selectbox")); 
Select currentSelect = new Select(currentElement);  
currentSelect.selectByVisibleText(updatedValue);     
currentElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);

System.out.println("milestoneA");
if ((exceptionExpected()) { 
    System.out.println("milestoneB");       
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());                            
    System.out.println("milestoneC");
    checkAlertBox(getExpectedResultFromExcel());                            
}
```

In DEBUG mode, the code keeps going fine and all is good.  In RUN mode in my logs I get up to milestoneB and then the above mentioned error is thrown.

Further to this, if I add a Thread.sleep(1000) before Tabbing, all works fine.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Is the selectbox focused when the timeout is raised?

Comment: No actually, the focus goes to the next element.  So what I did is I did a thread.sleep(3000) just before the sendKeys(Keys.TAB) and it worked!!  So I'm not sure what to do now.  Not really seeing an option that makes sense in the ExpectedConditions.  Any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to send the `TAB` key until the element loses the focus:

```
WebElement currentElement = driver.findElement(By.id("selectbox"));
currentElement.click();
currentElement.sendKeys("abcd");

// wait for the popup to be visible
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#abc")));

// send the TAB key while the current element has focus
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until((WebDriver wd) -> {
    currentElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    return !wd.switchTo().activeElement().equals(currentElement);
});
```

Comment: The focus is being lost though, because I can see that the next element in the page is being highlighted so I'm not sure about this.  Doing more research I found that it could be that my dropdown box is being populated dynamically so  I need to first wait for the option to turn up before tabbing.  This still doesn't make sense to me, because at the point that the next element becomes selected, I can see the option in the dropdown that it is available.

Comment: I just tried your code just in case, but still the same issue.  It works on DEBUG mode only.  Nice implementation though :)

Comment: Don't know if it helps but this is the HTML of the dropdown.                   * <select id="abc" class="controlclass" style="position: absolute; top: 65px; left: 150px; width: 80px; visibility: visible;" onblur="ServerFunction('LoseFocusFunc()')"  name="MyDropDown">
       <option value="001">abc</option>
       <option value="002">def</option>
       <option value="003">ghi</option>
       <option value=""></option>
        </select>

Comment: Why don't you wait for the drop down to appear before sending the TAB key?

Comment: I tried that too but same issue.  What I notice is that if I do a Thread.sleep(1000) before I tab, then everything works fine.  Going to update my question with this finding.

Comment: You need to wait for something in the page indicating that the field is ready to lose focus. There is not enough information to provide a better solution.

Comment: Hi Florent, I understand, thanks for your efforts though :)

Comment: Hi Florent, I just noticed a stupid thing.  When testing the site manually again I noticed that if I Tab to the dropdown, select a value using the keyboard quickly, and tab out (i.e. doing this in the space of half a second) the alert box never shows up!!  So this is actually a bug in the site :(  Sorry for finding this out only now, funnily enough the application has been in use for 15 years and this was never noted.